# Find the largest number that's adjacent to a zero

Tags: code-golf, number

**Challenge:**

Take a vector / list of integers as input, and output the largest number that's adjacent to a zero.

**Specifications:**

- As always, optional input and output format
- You may assume that there will be at least one zero, and at least one non-zero element.

**Test cases:**

```
1 4 3 6 0 3 7 0
7

9 4 9 0 9 0 9 15 -2
9

-4 -6 -2 0 -9
-2

-11 0 0 0 0 0 -12 10
0

0 20 
20
```

Good luck and happy golfing!

Comment: You should add a test case like the 4th one, but where the result is negative (there are positive numbers in the list).

Comment: I was going to try this in Retina, but then I noticed there are negatives. Retina hates negatives.

Comment: Don't let retina dictate what you can and cannot do. Take charge, you're the boss!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
ṡ2ẠÐḟS€Ṁ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmhMuG6oMOQ4bifU-KCrOG5gA&input=&args=LTQsLTYsLTIsMCwtOSwx)

```
ṡ2            Overlapping pairs
  ẠÐḟ         Remove pairs without zeroes
     S€       Sum of each pair
       Ṁ      Maximum
```

Answer (score 20):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

```
t~5BZ+g)X>
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dH41QlorZylYPg&input=Wy00IC02IC0yIDAgLTld) Or [verify all test cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YAp0fjVCWitnKVg-CkRU&input=WzEgNCAzIDYgMCAzIDcgMF0KWzkgNCA5IDAgOSAwIDkgMTUgLTJdClstNCAtNiAtMiAwIC05XQpbLTExIDAgMCAwIDAgMCAtMTIgMTBdClswIDIwXQ).

#### Explanation

Let's take input `[-4 -6 -2 0 -9]` as an example.

```
t     % Input array. Duplicate
      %   STACK: [-4 -6 -2 0 -9],  [-4 -6 -2 0 -9]
~     % Logical negate. Replaces zeros by logical 1, and nonzeros by logical 0
      %   STACK: [-4 -6 -2 0 -9],  [0 0 0 1 0]
5B    % Push logical array [1 0 1] (5 in binary)
      %   STACK: [-4 -6 -2 0 -9], [0 0 0 1 0], [1 0 1]
Z+    % Convolution, maintaining size. Gives nonzero (1 or 2) for neighbours of
      % zeros in the original array, and zero for the rest
      %   STACK: [-4 -6 -2 0 -9], [0 0 1 0 1]
g     % Convert to logical
      %   STACK: [-4 -6 -2 0 -9], [0 0 1 0 1]
)     % Use as index into original array
      %   STACK: [-2 -9]
X>    % Maximum of array.
      %   STACK: -2
      % Implicitly display
```

Comment: `x(~~(dec2bin(5)-48))`. Who's idea was it to implement that one? Very clever, and useful for logical arrays! :) Nice answer!

Comment: @WeeingIfFirst Thanks! I had used `dec2bin()-'0'` hundreds of times in MATLAB, so I knew that one had to be in MATL :-)

Comment: By the way, the fact that you included the content of the stack after every operation is worth an upvote alone. It makes it so much easier to understand (and possibly learn) MATL =)

Comment: Convolution Rocks. +1

Answer (score 11):

## Haskell, <s>63</s> 43 bytes

```
f x=maximum[a+b|(a,b)<-tail>>=zip$x,a*b==0]
```

Thanks to @MartinEnder for 4 bytes!

Comment: I think you can use `a*b==0` instead of the `||`.

Comment: You have to go back to previous version with zip. Here a and be are no longer adjacent

Comment: You don't need lambdabot here. This is "regular" Haskell

Answer (score 10):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
ü‚D€P_ÏOZ
```

**Explanation**

```
ü‚         # pair up elements
  D        # duplicate
   €P      # product of each pair (0 if the pair contains a 0)
     _     # logical negate, turns 0 into 1 and everything else to 0
      Ï    # keep only the pairs containing at least 1 zero
       O   # sum the pairs
        Z  # take max
```

Doesn't work in the online interpreter, but works offline.

Comment: This is amazing haha! Just in time :p.

Comment: @Adnan: Indeed. Awesome timing :)

Comment: Just implemented one of these operators or? :)

Comment: @WeeingIfFirst: `ü` was added just yesterday :)

Comment: Won’t this return `0` if the actual answer would be negative? You have to throw out the zeroes, I think.

Comment: @Lynn Nice catch! This can easily be fixed by replacing `˜` with `O` (sum).

Comment: @Lynn: Right you are. Thanks for catching that bug :)

Answer (score 9):

## Pyth, <strike>12</strike> <strike>11</strike> 10 bytes

```
eSsM/#0,Vt
```

Forms pairs, filters by zero member, sorts by sum, returns largest.

Comment: `,Vt` (implicit `QQ`) returns the same pairs as `.:Q2`, but with the pairs flipped. Should work, though.

Comment: `f}0T` is `/#0`

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>59</s> <s>57</s> 56 bytes

```js
let f =
    
l=>l.map((n,i)=>m=l[i-1]==0|l[i+1]==0&&n>m?n:m,m=-1/0)|m

console.log(f([1, 4, 3, 6, 0, 3, 7, 0]));       // 7
console.log(f([9, 4, 9, 0, 9, 0, 9, 15, -2]));  // 9
console.log(f([-4, -6, -2, 0, -9]));            // -2
console.log(f([-11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -12, 10]));  // 0
console.log(f([3, 0, 5]));                      // 5
console.log(f([28, 0, 14, 0]));                 // 28
```

*Edit: saved 2 bytes thanks to Huntro*
*Edit: saved 1 byte thanks to ETHproductions*

Comment: You can save two bytes by using `==` instead of `===`

Comment: I you can save a few bytes in several places: `l=>l.map((n,i)=>m=l[i-1]*l[i+1]==0&n>m?n:m,m=-1/0)|m`

Comment: Error: {
  "message": "Syntax error",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 15,
  "colno": 3
}

Comment: @RosLuP - This requires ES6 with arrow function support and won't work on all browsers (including, but not limited to: all IE versions before Edge, all Safari versions below v10, etc.)

Answer (score 7):

## Python, 49 bytes

```python
lambda a:max(sum(x)for x in zip(a,a[1:])if 0in x)
```

Tests are at **[ideone](http://ideone.com/bYp0HE)**

Zips through the pairs, sums the ones containing any zero, returns the maximum.

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES6), 53 bytes

```
a=>(m=-1/0,a.reduce((l,r)=>(m=l*r||l+r<m?m:l+r,r)),m)
```

Because I like using `reduce`. Alternative solution, also 53 bytes:

```
a=>Math.max(...a.map((e,i)=>e*a[++i]==0?e+a[i]:-1/0))
```

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, <s>77</s> <s>68</s> 71 bytes

<s>-3 bytes from anonymous,</s> -4 and -2 from MartinEnder

```
preg_match_all("#(?<=\b0 )\S+|\S+(?= 0)#",$argv[1],$m);echo max($m[0]);
```

run with `php -r '<code>' '<space separated values>'`

Comment: using `\K` to discard the match so far is shorter than using a look-behind.

Comment: You can also use space separation for input and then use `\S+` to match a signed integer. You'll probably have to use `\b0,` so you don't have to prepend the `,`.

Comment: Does this work for input like `4 0 0 5` ?

Comment: @TonHospel No. Does `\K` not work with alternatives? For unknown reason, the second alternative returns `0 0`, so that there is no more `0` to match before the `5`. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: Make a look at the other PHP solution with register_globals

Comment: @JörgHülsermann Take a look at my comment to that.

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby, 51 bytes

```
->a{a.each_cons(2).map{|a,b|a*b!=0?-1.0/0:a+b}.max}
```

#### usage

```
f=->a{a.each_cons(2).map{|a,b|a*b!=0?-1.0/0:a+b}.max}
p f[gets.split.map(&:to_i)]
```

Comment: I don't think you need the parentheses around `a+b`.

Comment: @Martin Ender syntax error occurs... https://ideone.com/F6Ed4B

Comment: It works in Ruby 2.3. (available here for instance: https://repl.it/languages/ruby)

Comment: @Martin Ender When I use "!=" instead of "==", it works. Thanks for your advice! https://ideone.com/F6Ed4B

Comment: There's a bug in there :(. `-3 -2 0` returns `0`. I think replacing `...?0:...` with `...?-1.0/0:...` should fix it, adding 5 bytes.

Comment: @m-chrzan I didn't notice that. Thanks for information.

Answer (score 4):

## Java 7, <s>118</s> <s>105</s> 106 bytes

```
int d(int[]a){int i=0,m=1<<31,c;for(;++i<a.length;m=a[i]*a[i-1]==0&(c=a[i]+a[i-‌​1])>m?c:m);return m;}
```

13 bytes saved thanks to *@cliffroot* by using an arithmetic approach instead. 1 additional byte thank to *@mrco* after he discovered a bug (the added test case `2, 1, 0` would return `2` instead of `1`).

**Ungolfed & test code:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/rBqgMX)

```
class M{
  static int c(int[] a){
    int i,
        m = a[i=0],
        c;
    for(; ++i < a.length; m = a[i] * a[i-1] == 0 & (c = a[i] + a[i - 1]) > m)
                           ? c
                           : m);
    return m;
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{ 1, 4, 3, 6, 0, 3, 7, 0 }));
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{ 9, 4, 9, 0, 9, 0, 9, 15, -2 }));
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{ -4, -6, -2, 0, -9 }));
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{ -11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -12, 10 }));
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{ 0, 20 }));
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{ 2, 1, 0 }));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
7
9
-2
0
20
1
```

Comment: slightly different approach using arithmetics, seems to be working
`int d(int[]a){int i,m=a[i=0],c;for(;++i<a.length;m=a[i]*a[i-1]==0&(c=a[i]+a[i-1])>m?c:m);return m;}`

Comment: The output is wrong, when the first number is not adjacent to 0, but larger than any number adjacent to 0. Reproducible by the test case {2, 1, 0}.
You can fix this by initializing i with 0 directly and m with 1<<31 (+1 overall).

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
SfµƝṀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z847dDWY3Mf7mz4f7hdM/L//2hDHQUTHQVjHQUzHQUDMMMcyIjVUYi2BMtYgoXhpKGpjoKuEUhaFyipawbigeV0LcGChoZgHjLSNQSqMAQbCeQZGcQCAA)

*-1 remembering it's not a dyadic chain*

```
  µƝ     For each pair of adjacent elements, monadically:
S        Sum the pair,
 f       and filter it to only element[s] in the pair.
    Ṁ    Take the maximum.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 7 bytes

```
qᵗZđ+aṀ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FmsKH26dHnVkonbiw50NS4qTkouhEgtuhkYb6pjoGOuY6RgASXMdg1iuaEugiCWQD8GGpjq6RkBRXRMdXTMgEyioawniGxoCmTCoa2ikYwjSbKBjZBALMR0A)

```
qᵗZđ+aṀ
q           Non-deterministically choose a contiguous subsequence
 ᵗZ         Check that it contains a 0
   đ        Unpair; check that its length is 2, and push the two elements
    +       Add
     a      All possible values
      Ṁ     Maximum
```

Answer (score 3):

### [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 16 bytes

```
q~2ew{0&},::+:e>
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cU4vezpROwoKUX4yZXd7MCZ9LDo6KzplPgoKXW59Lw&input=WzEgNCAzIDYgMCAzIDcgMF0KWzkgNCA5IDAgOSAwIDkgMTUgLTJdClstNCAtNiAtMiAwIC05XQpbLTExIDAgMCAwIDAgMCAtMTIgMTBd) (As a test suite.)

#### Explanation

```
q~    e# Read and eval input.
2ew   e# Get all (overlapping) pairs of adjacent values.
{0&}, e# Keep only those that contain a 0.
::+   e# Sum each pair to get the other (usually non-zero) value.
:e>   e# Find the maximum.
```

Answer (score 3):

## MATLAB with Image Processing Toolbox, 32 bytes

```
@(x)max(x(imdilate(~x,[1 0 1])))
```

This is an anonymous function. Example use for the test cases:

```
>> f = @(x)max(x(imdilate(~x,[1 0 1])))
f =
  function_handle with value:
    @(x)max(x(imdilate(~x,[1,0,1])))

>> f([1 4 3 6 0 3 7 0])
ans =
     7

>> f([9 4 9 0 9 0 9 15 -2])
ans =
     9

>> f([-4 -6 -2 0 -9])
ans =
    -2

>> f([-11 0 0 0 0 0 -12 10])
ans =
     0

>> f([0 20])
ans =
    20
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, <s>46</s> 43 bytes

<sup>*Saved 3 bytes due to [@MartinEnder](http://ppcg.lol/users/8478).*</sup>

```
Max[Tr/@Partition[#,2,1]~Select~MemberQ@0]&
```

Anonymous function. Takes a list of integers as input and returns an integer as output. Based off of the Ruby solution.

Answer (score 3):

### R, <strike>48</strike> 47 bytes

EDIT:
Fixed an error thanks to @Vlo and changed it to read input from stdins, saved one byte by assigning `w` and skipping parantheses.

```
function(v)sort(v[c(w<-which(v==0)-1,w+1)],T)[1]
```

```
v=scan();w=which(v==0);sort(v[c(w-1,w+1)],T)[1]
```

#### Unnested explanation

1. Find indices for which the vector `v` takes on the values 0: `w <- which(v == 0)`
2. Create new vector which contains the indices `+-1`: `w-1` and `w+1`
3. Extract elements that match the indices `w-1` and `w+1`
4. Sort in descending order and extract fist element

Note that if the last or first element of `v` is a zero, `w+-1` will effectively fetch an index outside of the length of the vector which implies that `v[length(v)+1]` returns `NA`. This is generally no problem but the `max()` functions inconveniently returns `NA` if there are any occurrences in the vector unless one specifies the option `na.rm=T`. Thus it is 2 bytes shorter to sort and extract first element than to use `max()`, e.g.:

```
max(x,na.rm=T)
sort(x,T)[1]
```

Comment: Need an extra parenthesis otherwise fails all test cases where max is to right of 0 such as `c(1, 4, 3, 6, 0, 10, 7, 0)`  `c((w<-which(v==0))-1,w+1)` Also a tad bit shorter with scan `sort((v<-scan())[c(w<-which(v==0)-1,w+1)],T)[1]`

Comment: @Vlo Thanks for pointing that obvious error out, +1. In your suggested solution you forgot the `()`too though ;). Updated the code and assigned `v` prior manipulation now.

Answer (score 3):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 14 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```apl
⌈/∊2(+↑⍨0∊,)/⎕
```

`⌈/` largest of

`∊` the flattened ("**e**nlisted"

`2(`...`)/` pairwise

`+` sum (zero plus something is something)

`↑⍨` taken if

`0` zero

`∊` is a member of

`,` the pair (lit. the concatenation of the left-hand number and the right-hand number)

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%7B%u2308/%u220A2%28+%u2191%u23680%u220A%2C%29/%u2375%7D%20%u22C4%20f%A8%281%204%203%206%200%203%207%200%29%289%204%209%200%209%200%209%2015%20%AF2%29%28%AF4%20%AF6%20%AF2%200%20%AF9%29%28%AF11%200%200%200%200%200%20%AF12%2010%29%280%2020%29&run)

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 14 bytes

```
|/+/'(*/')_2':
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJw1yUsOgDAIBNA9p5hd/YQUUNvQy7jrKTy8EGPIkMybOZ6617Jstay3lUE0oThxoEHidwj1RA/0oC96gY08Bz7BLVo4O4WmqUb9j9WgQpKLwARk8gIAqRQ1)

```
|/+/'(*/')_2':
           2':   pairs
     (*/')_      discard those whose product are nonzero
  +/'            sum of each pair
|/               maximum
```

Answer (score 2):

### Julia, <s>56</s> 55 Bytes

```
f(l)=max(map(sum,filter(t->0 in t,zip(l,l[2:end])))...)
```

Create tuples for neighboring values, take those tuples containing 0, sum tuple values and find maximum

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 42 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Give the numbers on line on STDIN

```
largest0.pl <<< "8 4 0 0 5 1 2 6 9 0 6"
```

`largest0.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
($_)=sort{$b-$a}/(?<=\b0 )\S+|\S+(?= 0)/g
```

Answer (score 2):

## J, 18 bytes

```
[:>./2(0&e.\#+/\)]
```

### Explanation

```
[:>./2(0&e.\#+/\)]  Input: array A
                 ]  Identity. Get A
     2              The constant 2
      (         )   Operate on 2 (LHS) and A (RHS)
               \    Get each subarray of size 2 from A and
             +/       Reduce it using addition
           \        Get each subarray of size 2 from A and
       0&e.           Test if 0 is a member of it
            #       Filter for the sums where 0 is contained
[:>./               Reduce using max and return
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `G`, 36 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 4.5 bytes

```
2lƛ∑w↔
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJHPSIsIiIsIjJsxpviiJF34oaUIiwiIiwiMSwgMCwgMSwgNywgMTAsIDAiXQ==)

Porting Jelly is (still) always the best option

### Explained

```
zṠ↔G­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
z     # ‎⁡Overlapping pairs (equivalent to 2l)
 Ṡ    # ‎⁢summed (vectorised)
  ↔   # ‎⁣with only items in the input kept.
   G  # ‎⁤Get the biggest number in that list.
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: Did you forget the update the code, TIO, and byte-count? `zṠ↔` is 3.375 bytes, isn't it? Or is it incorrect somehow, and you forgot to roll-back the explanation?

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 8.5 bytes

```
`/.|!$>>@:?$0+$]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWGxL09WoUVezsHKzsVQy0VWIhwlDZndFK0ZY6JjqWOgZQbGiqo2sUqxQLVQAA)

Disgustingly long…

```
`/.|!$>>@:?$0+$]
    !    :       Zip
     $            the input
      >>          with the tail of
        @         the input
   |             Filter by
          ?$0     containing a zero
  .              Map
             +$   sum
`/             ] Maximum
```

Answer (score 2):

## BQN, 14 bytes

```
⌈´((«∨»)0⊸=)⊸/
```

[Try](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RuKGkOKMiMK0KCjCq+KIqMK7KTDiirg9KeKKuC8KI0bihpB74oyIwrTwnZWpL8ucKMKr4oiowrspMD3wnZWpfQpGIDHigL804oC/M+KAvzbigL8w4oC/M+KAvzfigL8wCg==)

Seemed like a good excuse to use the shifts in `«∨»`.

Comment: 13: `⌈´(«∨»)∘=⟜0⊸/`

Comment: @Bubbler I was just coming here to post that exact solution!

Answer (score 2):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 16 bytes

```
}.>./@(+#~0=*)}:
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT0F9TQFWysFdR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxoVbPTk_fQUNbuc7AVkuz1goifLNNkys1OSNfwVzBViFNwVDBRMFYwQyo2RgoYgCRsgRLWQKlLIESEGxoqhBvBJGONwLLx5soxJuBOAYK8ZYQGQOIhKEhkAWD8YZGCoZQg40gCgyADIhrFiyA0AA)

```
}.>./@(+#~0=*)}:
}.            }:    Input without first and without last, respectively
          0=*       elementwise product equals 0?
       +            elementwise sum
        #~          filter the left by the right being true
                    (the right is true iff one of the two is zero,
                    and the corresponding sum is the other number)
  >./@              maximum of those
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3) `G`, 4 bytes

```
oᶻΠf
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJHIiwiIiwib+G2u86gZiIsIiIsIls5LCA0LCA5LCAwLCAxOSwgMSwgOSwgMTUsIC0yXSIsIjMuNC4yIl0=)

```
oᶻΠf­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏
o     # ‎⁡overlapping pairs
 ᶻΠ   # ‎⁢where the product is zero
   f  # flatten
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: 3 byters fail on [4,5,9,1,0,0]

Comment: Fails on `[9, 4, 9, 0, 19, 1, 9, 15, -2]`

Comment: @emanresuA luckily there were other 4 byters

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 74 Bytes

```
def f(x):x=[9]+x;print max(x[i]for i in range(len(x)) if 0in x[i-1:i+2:2])
```

Cycle through every element, if there's a `0` in the position of either the left or the right of the current element, include it in the generator, and then run it through `max`. We need to pad the list with some non-`0` number. It'll never be included because the slice `[-1:2:2]` won't include anything.

Answer (score 1):

## C# <s>76</s> 74 bytes

```
using System.Linq;i=>i.Zip(i.Skip(1),(a,b)=>a*b==0?1<<31:a+b).Max(‌​);
```

Explanation:

Use zip to join the array with itself but skipping the first value in the 2nd reference so that item zero joins to item one.  Multiply a times b, if the result is zero, one of them must be zero and output a + b.  Otherwise, output the minimum possible integer in the language.  Given the assumption that we will always have a zero and a non-zero, this minimum value will never be output as the max.

Usage:

```
[TestMethod]
public void LargestFriend()
{
    Assert.AreEqual(7, F(new int[] { 1, 4, 3, 6, 0, 3, 7, 0 }));
    Assert.AreEqual(9, F(new int[] { 9, 4, 9, 0, 9, 0, 9, 15, -2 }));
    Assert.AreEqual(-2, F(new int[] { -4, -6, -2, 0, -9 }));
    Assert.AreEqual(0, F(new int[] { -11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -12, 10 }));
    Assert.AreEqual(20, F(new int[] { 0, 20 }));
}
```

Comment: Hi. you can remove the space at `int[]i) {`. Also, I count 75 bytes in your current code (74 if you remove the space).

Comment: I think you can save 4 bytes by inverting the ternaries: `a?b?i.Min()).Max():a:b`

Comment: Plus `using System.Linq;`, no?

Comment: True but this question just asked for a method, not a full program and using `System.Linq;` is part of the default new class template.

Comment: @Grax Either way you need to include the `using` statement in your byte count

Comment: However compiling to a `Func<int[], int>` gets you 50 bytes + `using System.Linq;` for 68 bytes: `using System.Linq;i=>i.Zip(i.Skip(1),(a,b)=>a*b==0?1<<31:a+b).Max();`

Comment: Where do I find the instructions for this format?

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 182 bytes

**Golfed:**

```
DECLARE @x varchar(max)='1 5 4 3 6 1 3 17 1 -8 0 -7'

DECLARE @a INT, @b INT, @ INT WHILE @x>''SELECT @a=@b,@b=LEFT(@x,z),@x=STUFF(@x,1,z,''),@=IIF(@a=0,IIF(@b<@,@,@b),IIF(@b<>0 or @>@a,@,@a))FROM(SELECT charindex(' ',@x+' ')z)z PRINT @
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
DECLARE @x varchar(max)='1 5 4 3 6 1 3 17 1 -8 0 -7'

DECLARE @a INT, @b INT, @ INT
WHILE @x>''
  SELECT 
   @a=@b,
   @b=LEFT(@x,z),
   @x=STUFF(@x,1,z,''),
   @=IIF(@a=0,IIF(@b<@,@,@b),IIF(@b<>0 or @>@a,@,@a))
  FROM(SELECT charindex(' ',@x+' ')z)z 
PRINT @
```

**[Fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/542505/find-the-largest-number-thats-beside-a-zero)**

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell v3+, 62 bytes

```
param($n)($n[(0..$n.count|?{0-in$n[$_-1],$n[$_+1]})]|sort)[-1]
```

A bit longer than the other answers, but a nifty approach.

Takes input `$n`. Then loops through the indices `0..$n.count`, uses the `Where-Object` (`|?{...}`) to pull out those indices where the previous or next item in the array is `0`, and feeds those back into array slice `$n[...]`. We then `|sort` those elements, and take the biggest `[-1]`.

#### Examples

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> @(1,4,3,6,0,3,7,0),@(9,4,9,0,9,0,9,15,-2),@(-4,-6,-2,0,-9),@(-11,0,0,0,0,0,-12,10)|%{""+$_+" --> "+(.\largest-number-beside-a-zero.ps1 $_)}
1 4 3 6 0 3 7 0 --> 7
9 4 9 0 9 0 9 15 -2 --> 9
-4 -6 -2 0 -9 --> -2
-11 0 0 0 0 0 -12 10 --> 0

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> @(0,20),@(20,0),@(0,7,20),@(7,0,20),@(7,0,6,20),@(20,0,6)|%{""+$_+" --> "+(.\largest-number-beside-a-zero.ps1 $_)}
0 20 --> 20
20 0 --> 20
0 7 20 --> 7
7 0 20 --> 20
7 0 6 20 --> 7
20 0 6 --> 20
```

Answer (score 1):

## q, 38 bytes

```
{max x where 0 in'x,'(next x),'prev x}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when the maximum comes after a **0**. Also, I'm no q expert, but I think you would have to surround your code with `{}` to make it a function.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 53 bytes

```perl6
{max map ->$/ {$1 if !$0|!$2},(1,|@_,1).rotor(3=>-2)}
```

### Expanded:

```perl6
# bare block lambda with implicit signature of (*@_)
{
  max

    map

      -> $/ {           # pointy lambda with parameter ｢$/｣
                        # ( ｢$0｣ is the same as ｢$/[0]｣ )
        $1 if !$0 | !$2 # return the middle value if either of the others is false
      },

      ( 1, |@_, 1 )     # list of inputs, with added non-zero terminals
      .rotor( 3 => -2 ) # grab 3, back-up 2, repeat until less than 3 remain
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 66 bytes

```
foreach($a=$argv as$k=>$v)$v||$m=max($m,$a[$k-1],$a[$k+1]);echo$m;
```

Pretty straightforward. Iterates over the input, and when a number is `0`, it sets `$m` to the highest number of the 2 adjacent numbers **and** any previous value of `$m`.

Run like this (`-d` added for aesthetics only):

```
php -d error_reporting=30709 -r 'foreach($a=$argv as$k=>$v)$v||$m=max($m,$a[$k-1],$a[$k+1]);echo$m;' -- -4 -6 -2 0 -9;echo
```

Answer (score 1):

## SPSS Syntax (98 bytes)

Golfed solution:

```
CRE L=lead(A,1).
COMP R=MAX(lag(A),L).
EXE.
SEL IF A=0.
EXE.
AGG
/S=MAX(R).
LIST S
/CAS=1.
```

Ungolfed:

```
CREATE L=lead(A,1).
COMPUTE R=MAX(lag(A),L).
EXECUTE.
SELECT IF A=0.
EXECUTE.
AGGREGATE
/S=MAX(R).
LIST S
/CASES=1.
```

Explanation:
Input values is ordered vertically in a column. 
The first line of code creates a column with the lead number, the number before any given number. MAX(lag,A) returns the lagging number, the number after any given number (in test series A). So the second line of code creates a column with the highest number of neighbourging numbers of any given number. We are only interested in the neighbours of zeros, so the forth line selects all the rows with zeros, which now also include the highest valued neighbours. The 6th and 7th line of code finds the max value of selected neighbours.

With data inputs:

```
* This syntax solves: Returning the greatest adjacent number bigger or equal to itself,
  for any number V.
* CodeGolf asks for the solution for the case V=0.
* Bytes=98.

DATA LIST LIST
/ Sample (A7) a b c d e f g h i j k l m .
BEGIN DATA.
"A" 1, 4, 3, 6, 0, 3, 7, 0
"B" 9, 4, 9, 0, 9, 0, 9, 15, -2
"C" -4, -6, -2, 0, -9
"D" -11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -12, 10
"E"  0, 20
END DATA.
DATASET NAME Inputs WINDOW=FRONT.

FLIP VARIABLES=a b c d e f g h i
/NEWNAMES=Sample.
DATASET NAME CodeGolf WINDOW=FRONT.
DATASET CLOSE Inputs.

CRE L=lead(A,1).
COMP R=MAX(lag(A),L).
EXE.
SEL IF A=0.
EXE.
AGG
/S=MAX(R).
LIST S
/CAS=1.
```

Just change the sample references (A to E) for testing each sample.

Comment: I'm assuming your indentation is a bit off. Otherwise it's 126 bytes =)

Comment: Ok, thanks. Fixed that now.

Comment: What is SPSS syntax? Just curious. Also, welcome to PPCG!

Comment: @qwerp-derp Thank you for the welcome! :-) SPSS Syntax is a high-level data management programming language within the [_fourth generation of programming languages_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth-generation_programming_language) . It is used within IBM SPSS Statistics software package for statistical analysis.

Answer (score 1):

## R, <strike>48</strike> 54 bytes

```
s=scan()

w=which;max(s[c(w(s==0)+1,w(s==0)-1)],na.rm=T)
```

Reads vector from console input, then takes the maximum over all values adjacent to 0.

Edit: Catches NAs produced at the boundary, thanks rturnbull!

Comment: Am I doing it wrong? http://pastebin.com/0AA11xcw

Comment: This fails for cases such as `20 0`, because `s[w(s==0)+1]` returns `NA`, and `max`'s default treatment of `NA` is to return it. You can fix by adding the argument `na.rm=T`, or re-work the code to use `sort` (see the other R answer posted above).

Comment: Can you condense everything into one line? I don't know how to code in R, but I'm assuming you can.

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp: Not as far as I know. scan() waits for console input to read in the vector, the input stream is closed by entering an empty line. If you were to run the two lines as one, the second part would be at least partially recognized to be input for to the vector s.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `G`, 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ḣZæp}ʂ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPU9ORCZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOCVBM1olQzMlQTZwJTdEJUNBJTgyJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9MSUyMDQlMjAzJTIwNiUyMDAlMjAzJTIwNyUyMDAtJTNFNyUwQTklMjA0JTIwOSUyMDAlMjA5JTIwMCUyMDklMjAxNSUyMC0yLSUzRTklMEEtNCUyMC02JTIwLTIlMjAwJTIwLTktJTNFLTIlMEEtMTElMjAwJTIwMCUyMDAlMjAwJTIwMCUyMC0xMiUyMDEwLSUzRTAlMEEwJTIwMjAtJTNFMjAmZmxhZ3M9Q0c=)

##### Explanation

```python
ḣZæp}ʂ  # Implicit input
ḣZ      # All overlapping pairs
  æp}   # Filter by product == 0
     ʂ  # Sum each inner pair
        # Implicit output of maximum
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk`

---

```
gawk '{__=!_++?+$NF:!NF?(!_<__?__:!_):__<+(!RT||+$NF<+$!_? $!_:\
         $!_=$NF)?+$!_:__ }END{ print __ }' RS='(^| +)0([ \n]+|$)'
```

---

```
-11 0 0 0 0 0 -12 10
0
-4 -6 -2 0 -9
-2
0 20
20
1 4 3 6 0 3 7 0
7
9 4 9 0 9 0 9 15 
9
```

Comment: Is it possible in pure bash?

Comment: @Simd : any framework that's `Turing Complete` is always possible, question is ease of adaptability, which I have no idea, but my uneducated guess is that most likely it'd be rather verbose, given how one must space out arguments instead of clumping them like that in `awk`. The utter lack of typing in `awk` is a godsend without having to worry about integer-division only in `bash`, and any caveats when dealing with negatives, like the current question.

Comment: a lot of times I see code from those thinking maximizing things done within the `shell` is an ideal approach `"because it doesn't spawn extra PIDs"`, so they literally go down Alice in the Wonderland kind of rabbit holes trying handle some task that would be very seamless if it routed via `awk` / `sed` / `python` etc, and returning the result back to the shell.

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <del>106</del> 97 bytes

A port of [@Kevin Cruijssen's Java 7 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94050/110802) in Scala.

Saved 9 bytes thanks to the comment of [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY8xT8MwEIX3/IobfdSu4haK0sSVGBk6ISbU4TBp4ip2kWsVUJTfHlwjKgZysp5Oft@T3p00dTQeXw@1DrCFPsvgTB3oNTx4T18vjy7s1CYqqJHUpj@TZ4ZbrlGxnMuqWkqeY/nRmq5mvZkpWZqK5l3tmtAOaPaMmMGbKEKiUjlataXQzi19Jmf243CLpR1GgLd6D5aMY@Sb02@Jp@CNa3a4hmdnYpNYE@K8x9/QOaZZwpjkcMthyWHFIU/LfVwQ8V@6SHSR0KvKOw5iMRURMSBWFyLxopgEpUzE3ydkTMnJOpFYTJqX5PWUIRvGbw)

```scala
a=>{var(i,m,c)=(0,1<<31,0);while({i+=1;i<a.length})if(a(i)*a(i-1)==0)m=Math.max(a(i)+a(i-1),m);m}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY87T8MwFIX3/Ioz2tSu4haKUtKBkaETYkIMxqSJUWxQavFQld8ebqw0YWgk6/o@vnN1z9HoWnfdx@t7YQL2OCXAW3GAYXqL@6bRv88PPrzwLejDLs6BL93AUpWOlaNKIc@xVmPPnEVpEnvfla0LsJPFguA72pBDL@vCl6Fq@bAasAcwzSzHFeiDhOLY0ZKJAAxtjcxiYsZhf8teh2rp9A8zAo4PozaZokv6bHDrtPVMN@Xx7PkxNNaXve0nbyffn9QNtWeGRYwpgWuBtcBGII3JLSWc84t0FuksomNUNwJyNSeRJJCbnoi8zGZBpSLx/0lFKjV7DhGr2WGvHK20Sdt1fw)

```scala
object M {
  def c(a: Array[Int]): Int = {
    var i = 0
    var m = 1 << 31
    var c: Int = 0

    while ({i += 1; i < a.length}) {
      if (a(i) * a(i - 1) == 0) {
        c = a(i) + a(i - 1) 
        m = Math.max(c, m)
      }
    }
    m
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(c(Array(1, 4, 3, 6, 0, 3, 7, 0)))
    println(c(Array(9, 4, 9, 0, 9, 0, 9, 15, -2)))
    println(c(Array(-4, -6, -2, 0, -9)))
    println(c(Array(-11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -12, 10)))
    println(c(Array(0, 20)))
    println(c(Array(2, 1, 0)))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 15 bytes

```
M$|*:0N_FIgZ@>g
```

Takes the numbers as command-line arguments. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhbrfVVqtKwM_OLdPNOjHOzSIaIwyWhdEx1dMx1dIx0DHV3LWKgwAA)

#### Explanation

```lisp
M$|*:0N_FIgZ@>g
          g      ; List of command-line args
           Z     ; Zip with
            @>g  ; All but the first element of that same list
        FI       ; Filter those pairs of elements on this function:
     0N_         ;   Contains a 0
 $|*:            ; Fold each pair on logical OR
M                ; Maximum
```

Answer (score 0):

### Racket 183 bytes

```
(λ(k)(let*((lr(λ(l i)(list-ref l i)))(l(append(list 1)k(list 1)))(m(for/list((i(range 1(sub1(length l))))
#:when(or(= 0(lr l(sub1 i)))(= 0(lr l(add1 i)))))(lr l i))))(apply max m)))
```

Detailed version:

```
(define f
 (λ(k)
    (let* ((lr (λ(l i)(list-ref l i)))
           (l (append (list 1) k (list 1)))
           (m (for/list ((i (range 1 (sub1(length l))))
                         #:when (or (= 0 (lr l (sub1 i)))
                                    (= 0 (lr l (add1 i))) ))
                (lr l i) )))
      (apply max m) )))
```

Testing:

```
(f (list 1 4 3 6 0 3 7 0))
(f (list 9 4 9 0 9 0 9 15 -2))
(f (list -4 -6 -2 0 -9))
(f (list -11 0 0 0 0 0 -12 10))
(f (list 0 20 ))
```

Output:

```
7
9
-2
0
20
```

Answer (score 0):

## C 132 bytes

Outputs using main's return code:

```
int main(int a,char**_){int i,m=0;_[0]=_[a]="1";for(i=1;i<a;++i){m=(*_[i-1]-48||*_[i+1]-48?m>atoi(_[i])?m:atoi(_[i]):m);}return m;}
```

I feel like I should be able to save a few bytes by saving one of the atoi calls, but I couldn't find an efficient way. (`,t` plus `t=` plus `,` plus `t` twice is too long). Also this *technically* uses undefined behaviour (setting _[a] to "1") but every compiler I know of allows it by default.

Strategy: pad the start and end of the array with 1, then loop over the internal section checking each neighbor.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP <s>69</s> 64 bytes

Some bytes on and off from Jörg Hülsermann and Titus. = `(-5)`

Requires register_globals enabled. Usage: `http://localhost/notnull.php?i[]=9&i[]=-5i[]=...`

```
$x=$_GET['i'];
$y=0;
foreach($x as $j){
if($y<abs($j)){
$y=$j;
}
}
echo $y;
```

Golfed:

```
$x=$_GET['i'];$y=0;foreach($x as $j)if($y<abs($j))$y=$j;echo $y;
```

Comment: Why do not use directly the input as array. I could not seen the reason for json_encode.

Comment: For non-default settings you have to add the full length of the setting change to your byte count. (see http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4778#4778) In this case +21 bytes for `-d register_globals=1` (or specify a version where register_globals is enabled by default)

Comment: But `json_decode` is a nice idea.

Comment: @Titus What I mean is `?id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3`  and then `$_GET["id"]` gives back an array. For this reason json_decode makes no sense for me

Comment: @JörgHülsermann It costs bytes, but it´s still a nice idea.

Comment: This answer is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

## YASEPL, 91 bytes

```
=1'±" "=l®1=h-99=i`1!o¥i,1}7,0,2!i]4!m$i-=s¥m,1}2,h,2|3`4!m$i+=s¥m,1}2,h,2`3!h$s`2!i+}2,l>h
```

explained:

```
=1'±" "=l®1=h-99=i`1!o¥i,1}7,0,2!i]4!m$i-=s¥m,1}2,h,2|3`4!m$i+=s¥m,1}2,h,2`3!h$s`2!i+}2,l>h                   packed
=1'                                                                                                           set var1 to user input
   ±" "                                                                                                       split A by every space
       =l®1                                                                                                   set L to the length of var1
           =h-99                                                                                              set H to -99 (atorage for highest number)
                =i                                                                                            set I to 0 (incrementer)
                  `1                                                              !i }2,l                     do while I < L ...
                    !o¥i,1}7,0,2                                                `2                               if(var1[i] == 0) ...
                                !i]4!m$i-=s¥m,1}2,h,2|3`4                 `3                                         and if(i != 0 and if(var1[i-1] > h) ...
                                                         !m$i+=s¥m,1}2,h,2                                           or if(var1[i+1] > h) ...
                                                                            !h$s                                        set H to S and continue (found higher number)
                                                                                    +                            increment I and loop.
                                                                                         >h                   print H once done.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Feb-17)</sup>, 14 bytes

```
/↥≡/+▽=0≡/×.◫2
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_9_0__ZiDihpAgL-KGpeKJoS8r4pa9PTDiiaEvw5cu4perMgoKZiBbMSA0IDMgNiAwIDMgNyAwXQpmIFs5IDQgOSAwIDkgMCA5IDE1IMKvMl0KZiBbwq80IMKvNiDCrzIgMCDCrzldCmYgW8KvMTEgMCAwIDAgMCAwIMKvMTIgMTBdCmYgWzAgMjBdCg==)

```
/↥≡/+▽=0≡/×.◫2
            ◫2  # overlapping pairs
           .    # duplicate
        ≡/×     # products
     ▽=0        # keep those equal to zero
  ≡/+           # sums
/↥              # max
```